# Visual Studio and Gulp

Tags: c#, angularjs, visual-studio-2015, npm, gulp

I am trying to run Gulp in Visual Studio for an angular app. Unfortunately I am getting this error:

```
Cannot evaluate the item metadata "%(FullPath)". The item metadata "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied to the path 
"node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\dateformat\node_modules\meow\node_modules\normalize-package-data\node_modules\
hosted-git-info\test\bitbucket-https-with-embedded-auth.js". C:\Users\AIUZS03\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MacroGraph\MacroGraph\
node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\dateformat\node_modules\meow\node_modules\normalize-package-data\node_modules\
hosted-git-info\test\bitbucket-https-with-embedded-auth.js
```

I understand the error and that the folder structure of the Gulp library is too long, but has anyone had any luck with a workaround so I can use Gulp and other Gulp libraries? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a known problem; msbuild has problem with paths that are longer than 260 characters. Your particular issue can be avoided by flattening your npm dependencies using `npm dedupe`.

Reference: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe

Comment: Thanks for the help. I looked into this and I ended up upgrading NPM and Node, which solved my issue. It looks like the newer version of NPM doesn't create the never ending hierarchy, but instead does it all at the root.

Comment: It's not an msbuild issue, it's a Windows issue. Windows does not support file paths longer than 260 characters.